# Index page separate from rest of AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on two projects right now using AngularJS, and I'm running into the same problem with both of them.

The problem is that I have an index page that looks completely different from any of the inner pages, which means that my `ng-view` has to consist of the entire page. This makes it so that any time a route changes, the whole page has to reload instead of just the main content area. This causes things like the header or sidebar to flash briefly.

The only good approach I can think of to make my index page separate from my app is to literally have a separate, static `index.html` and then all my angularJS pages inside a separate folder so that I can use a more focused `ng-view`.

Is this the only/best approach there is? Has anyone achieved this, or have any ideas on how to? thanks.

Comment: How about using ng-show to show the parts (header/navigation/etc) that aren't on the "index" page conditionally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to solve this problem would be using [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

For example:

You could have an `app.html` which is a page that holds all of your application views. In it add a:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

and styles/scripts required by the entire application.

All of your views will go there including the `index.html` view.

Assuming that the pages except the index have some sort of header/body/footer layout in which the body changes according to the actual page you can use a configuration as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider)
{
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/index',
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'IndexController'
        })
        .state('root', {
            templateUrl: 'root.html',
            controller: 'RootController'
        })
        .state('root.somePage', {
            url: '/some-page',
            templateUrl: 'some-page.html',
            controller: 'SomePageController'
        })
        .state('root.anotherPage', {
            url: '/another-page',
            templateUrl: 'another-page.html',
            controller: 'AnotherPageController'
        });
}
```

The `root.html` will be like a masterpage in ASP.NET Webforms so it would be in the form:

```
<!-- header markup here -->

<div ui-view></div>

<!-- footer markup here -->
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I need. Does the stateProvider replace the routeProvider?

Comment: @Jakemmarsh, that is my understanding of it, that it replaces routeProvider, adding multilevel views/states: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki